# No authorization header

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I'm creating a ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API, everything works really well but I'm having a problem with Swashbuckle. I have added a basic authentication to my API and enabled the basic scheme to Swasbuckle:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Basic", new BasicAuthScheme { Description = "Basic authentication" });
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

When I access to the SwaggerUI everything works fine, I see the authorization scheme and I can add the user name and password. The problem happens when calling any api, the Authorization header is never sent to the API controllers.

Do I need to do anything else in order to tell Swasbuckle it must send the authorization header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, finally I found what was missing. You need to add a document filter in order to get Swashbuckle send the authorization:

```
public class BasicAuthFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var securityRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()
        {
            { "Basic", new string[] { } }
        };

        swaggerDoc.Security = new[] { securityRequirements };
    }
}

//In the Startup class...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Basic", new BasicAuthScheme { Description = "Basic authentication" });
            c.DocumentFilter<BasicAuthFilter>();
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```